# matlab division by vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab, division

Where can I find the the documentation for this sort of division and output? Why is the results different from 1./a?

```
a = [4,5,6,8]

>> 1/a'

ans =

     0         0         0    0.1250
```

Comment: Because matlab defaults to matrix algebra.  So 1/a is the multiplicative inverse of (matrix) a, i.e. a*(1/a) = 1 (or eye(d)) where * is interpreted as matrix multiply. (doesn't seem quite to work in your example, but that's the idea).

Comment: what is d here? I also edited the answer, it should be 1/a' not 1/a,otherwise you are right it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arrays, the operand `/` is the [`mrdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) function: the result of B/A will be one solution of the linear system `xA=B`.

It is completely different from the operand `./`, which corresponds to the [`rdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) function.

Note that, as stated in the comments, [a scalar in Matlab is treated as a 1x1 matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html).

Comment: are you saying that 1 is interpreted as a 1x1 matrix [1]?

Comment: actually it looks like you are right but the documentation does not actually explicitly specify the case where B(not A) is a scalar..

Comment: Yes, I think in Matlab a scalar and a 1x1 matrix are the same

Comment: This seems to be confirmed by the following page of Matlab documentation: [Empty Matrices, Scalars, and Vectors](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html)

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf: You are right, for a very short answer refer to `doc isscalar`, it's a scalar if and only if size returns `[1,1]`

Answer (score 0):

You are asking matlab to solve the equitation `x*[4,5,6,8]'=1`, one possible solution is `[0,0,0,.125]`